# Simulating Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, simulation

I'm wondering if it is possible to simulate the Poisson distribution using the Alias Method, because we suppose to use this method for discrete random variables with finite support. So I think finite support means finite cardinal(is it right?).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_%28mathematics%29

Comment: Thank you, so can we conclude that it is not possible to simulate P.D with the Alias Method?

Comment: I'd say yes. The algorithm depends on the set being finite. That is also where the time complexity $O(n)$ or $O(n\log n)$ comes from: the $n$ is the number of points with non-zero probability. See the original paper for details. (wiki has a link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon comments, the alias method will only allow you to "sample" from the Poisson distribution if you approximate by saying that for some large $N$, $P(X = n) = 0$ for all $n \geq N$ for your random variable that is almost Poisson.

Comment: So, if we send a finite set of probabilities, I mean $n$ $P_{i}$'s, then we will obtain an "aproximation" for the Poisson distribution, right?

Comment: @FacundoGFlores anothor possibility might be to use "Truncated Distribution" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution . Note this will result in a real distribution (with $\sum_ip_i = 1$) while this answer doesn't.